# flutter app crashed on internal testing ( work fine on my phone )

Tags: android, flutter

When I install the local apk or debugged version it works fine **(My project is in release mode)**but when I upload the app-release apk on google play store (Internet Testing) and download the app experience crashes and does not start.
Both the app-release.apk worked nor app.apk crashed when I installed it on my phone or uploaded on play store.

Answer (score 1):

From Google Play consoi, got to `pre launch report` then go to performance, you will find that your app was tested on multiple devices automatically, and you will find out how many of them crashed. So now you can check the crashes stack trace and exactly what is the issue.